# Apple push notification error when triggered through erlang

Tags: ssl, erlang, apple-push-notifications, ejabberd

I am trying to trigger an Apple push notification. My code is:

```
-module(ssltest).
-export([sendpush/0]).

sendpush() ->
    Address = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com",
    Port = 2195,
    Cert = "/usr/lib/erlang/bin/MantuPush/cert.pem",
    Key = "/usr/lib/erlang/bin/MantuPush/key.pem",  
    Options = [{certfile, Cert}, {keyfile, Key}, {mode, binary}],
    Timeout = 1000,
    {ok, Socket} = ssl:connect(Address, Port, Options, Timeout),
    Payload = mochijson2:encode({struct, [{"aps", [{"alert", "This is Message"}]}]}),
    BPayload = erlang:list_to_binary(Payload),
    PayloadLen = erlang:byte_size(BPayload),
    Token = "7518b1c2c7686d3b5dcac8232313d5d0047cf0dc0ed5d753c017ffb64ad25b60",
    BToken = hex:hexstr_to_bin(Token),
    BTokenLength = erlang:byte_size(BToken),
    SomeID= 1,
    {MSeconds,Seconds,_} = erlang:now(),
    Expiry = MSeconds * 1000000 + Seconds + 3600*1,
    Packet = "1:8, SomeID:32/big, Expiry:32/big, BTokenLength:16/big, BToken/binary, PayloadLen:16/big, BPayload/binary",
    ssl:send(Socket, Packet),
    ssl:close(Socket).
```

But every time it gives the following error:

```
{error,{keyfile,{badmatch,{error,{asn1,{wrong_tag,{{expected,16},  {got,65565,{65565,<<243,247,242,108,193,12,122,139,140,60,...>>}}}}}}}}}
```

Any clues?

Comment: As you can see from the error description, the problem is with your certificate.

Comment: yes the problem was in certificate.Now it is working fine

Comment: was it a certificate that was created on a windows machine and moved to unix / OS X or vis-a-versa? There reason I ask is because the DOS version would contain control-M terminators which would annoy the other OS's

Comment: Hey @Geek, What did you follow to generate the certs?
I have a siliar issue. It says:  :       

{error,{keyfile,{badmatch,{error,{asn1,{wrong_tag,{{expected,16},
                                                         {got,131086,
                                                                    {131086,<<120,20,87,27,102,215,45,144,54,160,...>>}}}}}}}}}